# Windows 10 "synchronized" logins

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts

I really don't how I should describe this problem in few words...

Let start with the setup first: I have a computer (desktop model) with Windows 10 Home installed (version 1709, OS build somewhere in 16000). There are two accounts on that device:

- (1) A **local *administrator*** account and
- (2) a **local** account.

Both have different names and passwords.

When I boot up the pc, I arrive at my log in screen. Dependent of the last used account in my previous session, either (1)'s name or (2)'s name shows up.

**SCENARIO 1**: Boot up. The display name is of account (2). I switch to (1). Then I sign in my account (1). I see a welcome splash screen that shows for a second before showing the desktop. This is weird at first because that welcome splash should only appear after a mayor update. That is because the setting* is turned on. Anyways, that is not important. I do my stuff and after a while, I want to shut down the pc. So window key -> tab -> power icon -> shut down.

Suddenly, I get a message that *there is another used logged in*: account (2). I have to press OK to shut down that account too. But I did not have signed in with that account in this session!

**SCENARIO 2**: Boot up. The display name is of account (1). I sign in my account (1). No welcome splash + no *there is another used logged in* message when shutting down the PC. The other account remains not signed in. So that is OK.

**SCENARIO 3**: Boot up. The display name is of account (1). I switch to account (2). Then I sign in my account (2). Same problem as at scenario 1: I get a welcome splash screen and when shutting down, I get a *there is another used logged in* message. The other administrator account is signed in while I did not have provided credentials on that ...

**SCENARIO 4**: Boot up. The display name is of account (2). I sign in my account (2). No welcome splash + no *there is another used logged in* message when shutting down the PC. Also the correct behavior like in scenario 2.

So in short, somehow when I am switching to another account when I want to log in with that account, Windows 10 signs in with BOTH (1) and (2) accounts. As if both profiles are "synchronized" together. This should NOT happen.

Since I could not describe this problem in few words, my google fu did not led to results of which has solved my problem. What I did is (tbf, almost all steps I got via google is summarized [here](https://windowsreport.com/corrupt-user-profile-windows-10/)

- untick the welcome settings*
- reset both accounts via Powershell (reload manifest and ect)
- [fixing via registry](https://www.techbout.com/fix-corrupt-user-profile-windows-10-9139/)
- the "run dism / sfc scan"

Not sure if "create an account + copy over user data" trick would help. Re-installing the OS would be a canon-shot. So I figured to ask here first to see if it could be resolved easily.

So, does anyone know how to resolve this?

* setting: "Settings" -> "System (display, notifications, power)" -> "Notifications & actions"

> Show me the Windows welcone experience after updates and occassionally when I sign in to highlight what's new and suggested

is turned **on**.

Comment: This sounds a lot like another question from about 2 weeks ago where programs were starting and users were being logged in, and it turned out Cortana was doing all this. I'm trying to find the duplicate but cannot at the moment.

Comment: @music2myear can you add more clues/pointers about that question? Eg try to recall the content of the text. I have tried to search by `created:2017-01..2017-01 [windows] or [windows-10] -[active-directory]` 
 and with keywords "cortana", "user(s) login" "startup". But could not find a related question.

Comment: I recall the solution pointed to Cortana, but the question didn't. I recall the question was about another account being logged on automatically and running processes after a restart. But I can't recall any specific words from the question. It's been bugging me for a few days now as I try to remember more details.

Comment: @music2myear could solve it. Thanks for at least some pointers. Cortana was a part of the problem. Already answered my own question for future users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading [music2myyear's comments](https://superuser.com/questions/1288107/windows-10-synchronized-logins#comment1912622_1288107) comments, I started to dig in the archives of this network. After reading through numerous questions/answers after narrowing down the search (I have expanded it with a month to be sure), I have made a selection. From those selection, there was a feature that was causing culprit among similar like problem or related problems (weird auto-start).

Aaand ... finally solved the problem. I had to combine two things to fix this problem. The first one is located in `Settings -> Accounts -> Sign-in options -> Privacy`. The second option

> Use my sign-in info to automatically finish setting up my device after an update or restart

was enabled. I have turned it off at my **local *administrator*** account and my **local** account.

[image: Sign-in options: privacy setting]

But that was not enough .

Then I recalled a super user question where (could not find it anymore) Windows were not shutting down clearly when using the shutdown power option at the start menu. (I shutdown my pc via the start menu because you can go to there with some quick keystrokes)

After investigating that, I discovered that using that shutdown option does not shutdown windows "directly". There is a script hooked on that (involves firing an event to Cortana and other things). So it may be an influence. In order to cleanup the users session completely, I have used a "pure" shutdown: either with Alt+F4 on desktop screen or via ps with `logoff` command. I have used the former to log off my **local account** as administrator via ps. Then I issued a `shutdown` command. After that, I booted the pc and logged in at my **local account**. The admin session was not logged in at the same moment. So it is fixed now

Whew, the hours spent skimming those questions and answers were worth of my time.